# Angular Typescript correct way to convert string to date irrespective of timezone?

Tags: angular, typescript, date

I am using Angular version 10 and has typescript 3.9 .

I am trying to convert the string (only date, no time) to Date object and it is adding the 1 day to it. I am not using "now", just passing the actual date string value (past values too). For example trying this on playground (today is 7th dec not 31st, so "now" or current time does not matter):

```
const anExampleVariable = "Hello World"
console.log(anExampleVariable)

let valDate = null;
const dateStr = "2022-11-31"
var parts = dateStr.trim().replace(/ +(?= )/g,'').split(/[\s-\/:]/)
valDate = new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2])
console.log(valDate)
```

The output us as follows:

```
[LOG]: "Hello World" 
[LOG]: Date: "2022-12-01T05:00:00.000Z"
```

Why is it adding one day to the string passed?
How do I "simply" convert the date(only) string to Date object?

Comment: Can you try with a different date? There is no Nov 31st, so that might be causing the problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks Mark, sorry my bad. Lots of other things in mind, copied Oct date as Nov without realizing the "day". Seems fine for now. Thanks for pointing out such a typo.

Comment: There was a typo on the code. Fixing the typo fixes the code (and effectively nullifies the question).